# Visual Studio - Error List

Tags: asp.net

My Error List shows my Warnings in the List but not the Errors.  When I click on Warnings, I get a list of them all but when I click on Errors nothing shows.

There's no errors listed and I've checked that the Filter is correct.

Please see attached.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: are you sure
1. you actually have any errors?
2. you've clicked/toggled also the errors button?

Comment: "Please see attached." Realy? You don't copy-paste your client's request, don't you?